# Socket permissions when running Django with FastCGI

Tags: python, django, deployment, fastcgi

I am running Django fcgi with standard line:

```
exec setuidgid $USERID $VENVBIN/python $WEBAPP/manage.py runfcgi daemonize=false socket=$FCGISOCKET
```

Problem is that only group is shared between fastcgi process and webserver, not user - however group do not have write permissions by default (hotfix is running chmod g+w manually).

How to force process to make socket in mode 0770?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`./manage.py runfcgi help` says:

umask=UMASK          umask to use when daemonizing (default 022).

So you just need to run:

```
./manage.py runfcgi socket=$FCGISOCKET umask=007
```

and a socket with mode 0770 will be created. Please note that umask is being set only when daemonize is set to true (which is default).

Comment: I tried variety of umask settings, but they all create srwxr-xr-x permissions for me :-/

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to run it with `daemonize=false`?

Comment: You are right, I cannot read properly. However, daemonize=true prevents me from using daemontools to supervise the process...is there any way to use umask with it?

Comment: Seems like there is no way to do that. Code sets umask only when daemonizing. It can be fixed in one line of code in django.core.servers.fastcgi. But it would be another not very good approach. I would really like to know why django developers made umask unusable without daemonizing

Answer (score 1):

can't find a way to do this with fastcgi, added a os.fchmod at the end of my settings.py and that seems to make it work. still its a horrible hack and they should allow you to set it when invoking the service.

Comment: Yes, using similar hack, but I would really like to avoid it :]

Answer (score 1):

`umask=` doesn’t work when running with `daemonize=false`. In this case, it’ll just use your current os umask, so run `umask 0007` before your script.